# React (Lists and Keys) mapping appends old items to new items on re render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have this strange problem - when the component renders it displays the comments that belong to a post, however when I choose to display the comments for a different post, the comments from the first post don't get removed. It displays comments from the previous and current posts in the second component render.

FYI, the comment ids are all unique and used for the list `keys`... If I use the list index for the `keys` instead, the problem is resolved and it renders properly... so i'm not sure why this is happening.

**Example code**

**Redux store**

```
postId: 'postId1' //this gets updated whenever I dispatch an action to view a new post (comments)

posts: [
  postId1: {
    ...post details
    comments: ['id1', 'id2'],

  },
  postId2: {
    ...post details
    comments: ['id3', 'id4'],

  }
];

comments: [
 id1: {
   ...comment details
 },
 id2: {
   ...comment details
 },
 id3: {
   ...comment details
 },
 id4: {
   ...comment details
 },
];
```

**Click event in another component**

```
const handlePostClick = postId => event => {
    dispatch(selectPostRequestAction(postId));
  };
```

**Action**

```
export const selectPostRequestAction = postId => {
  return {
    type: types.SELECT_POST_REQUEST,
    postId,
  };
};
```

**Reducer**

```
const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  postId: null,
  comments: [],
};

export const postManagerReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.SELECT_POST_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        postId: action.postId,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**React component**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import Comment from './comment';

const PostsContainer = (props: Props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { posts, postId, comments} = useSelector(
    ({ postManager }) => postManager
  );

  if (!postId) return null;

  const post = posts[postId];

   return (
     post.comments.map((commentId, index) => (
       <Comment
         key={commentId}
         index={index}
         comment={comments[commentId]}
       />
     ))
   );
};

export default PostsContainer;
```

**First render**

```
<div>comment</div>
<div>comment</div>
<div>comment</div>
```

**Second render (current results)**

```
//comments from second render
<div>comment</div>
<div>comment</div>
//comments from first render
<div>comment</div>
<div>comment</div>
<div>comment</div>
```

**Second render (expected results)**

```
//comments from second render
<div>comment</div>
<div>comment</div>
```

Comment: It would seem that the flaw in your design is actually wherever you are dispatching and hence pushing new comments to your store, which we can't see.

Comment: Hey @George when I click on a new post link, I dispatch an action with the new postId which updates the redux store and re renders the component... am I missing something?

Comment: Can you share your selector and your action?

Comment: @Domino987 post has been updated.

Comment: Looks fine, can you create a sandbox to reproduce that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing all of the `posts` to the component, use selectors/filters to get that single post you need, then pass it through `useSelector`.

---

My version of the implementation would look like this:

```js
//myComponent.js
  const { post } = useSelector(
    (state) => ({
      post: postSelector(state)
    })
  );
```

```js
// selectors.js
// You can use reselect library or redux-toolkit
import { createSelector } from "reselect";
const getPosts = (state) => state.postsManager.posts
const getPostId = (state) => state.postsManager.postId

export const postSelector = createSelector(
  [getPosts, getPostId],
  (posts, postId) => {
      if(posts[postId]){ // or use some other checking
         return posts[postId];
   }

  }
);
```

If you are going to stick with *list indexing*, a better *posts* state would look like this:

```js
...
posts:[
  {
     postId: ...
     postDetails: ...
     ...
  },
  {
     postId: ...
     postDetails: ...
     ...
  },
  {
     postId: ...
     postDetails: ...
     ...
  },
   ...
]
...
```